# Have CiviCRM follow CMS language with Joomla

Tags: profile, joomla, language

I currently have CiviCRM 5.25.0 and Joomla 3.9.19.

Joomla is bilingual Fr / En and users can switch from one language to the other no problem.

CiviCRM is set up bilingual with Fr as the default language, but all fields are defined in both languages (Fr_CA & En_US).

I have set the "Inherit CMS language” option to YES.

I set up in Joomla two URL Menus (one in Fr and one in EN) to list a contact group.

In the French site, I see the profiles fields in French, as it should. But when I switch to the English in the frontend, the menus are in English, as expected, but the profile remains in French.

If I switch the CiviCRM default language to En, then the English side is OK (the users see the profile fields in English) but  French users also see the profile in En even though the Menus are nos in Fr.

It thus seems that the profile follows the default CiviCRM language and not the CMS language.

I have tried to force the language by adding “&lcMessages=en_US” at the end of the English Menu URL - as I found in some forums - to no avail. Just in case, I have also tried en_UK.

Any idea on how to force the profile to follow the user’s language preference?

Just in case it is needed, here is the English page: https://www.voile.qc.ca/en/?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/profile&Itemid=609&force=1&gid=14&lcMessages=en_US
Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, CiviCRM doesn't support automatic inheritance of the language in Joomla, yet.

But your idea to add lcMessages in the url was good. I was able to make it work using lcMessages=en_CA. It seems that you have set up your site in en_CA locale, not the default en_US.

The full url should be : https://www.voile.qc.ca/en/?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/profile&Itemid=609&force=1&gid=14&lcMessages=en_CA